# Update mutiple tables using case and subquery MySql

Tags: php, mysql, subquery, case, multiple-tables

I'm restructuring some code, this is a PHP - MYSQL project. So i'm trying to update some tables in a single query or at least two.

Is this possible to achieve without Joins? What is the best choice ?

```
UPDATE document D SET D.status = 2,
    CASE 
        WHEN D.type 'A' THEN (UPDATE table_1 SET active = 1 WHERE id_table1 = D.id_document)
        WHEN D.type 'B' THEN (UPDATE table_2 SET active = 1 WHERE id_table2 = D.id_document)
        WHEN D.type 'C' THEN (UPDATE table_3 SET active = 1 WHERE id_table3 = D.id_document)            
    END 
WHERE D.id_document = %s
```

I don't mind to separate the first table " document D ", but I need the " case when " to update multiple tables in a single query because they are like 11 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to leave the question unanswered. Based on what I researched.

- No, you can not do an "update" in a subquery.
- No, you can not use the "case" like that.

The only thing that can be done is:

Use joins to update multiple tables

```
UPDATE table_1
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_1.id = table_2.id
INNER JOIN table_3 ON table_3.id = table_3.id
SET table_1.column = '', table_2.column = ''
WHERE any condition;
```

And the "case" can only be used in a single way

```
UPDATE table SET
column = CASE columX WHEN 'A' THEN '2' ELSE column END,
column2 = CASE columX WHEN 'B' THEN '2' ELSE column2 END
```

Combining the two, I was able to achieve what I needed.

Remember that you can make different types of join and play with the "where". In the "case" clause, updating the column is mandatory, not optional, so I use the same column in "else" to leave it with the default value when I do not need to update that column.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put it all in one query to improve performance? That won't help in this case, since it will take the same amount of time as it would if each subquery were executed separately.

You would get much cleaner code and better performance if you determined the table name in your php code and then passed that onto a much simpler query string.

Comment: This old code has so many "mysqli_query()" calls, like 32 just for a simple repetitive update. Just wanted to reduce the amount of lines. Also I use simple sql for fast Copy/Paste to do tests. 

I could put the tables in an array and build and execute. I'm trying to avoid to build the sql with php

Comment: Sorry, there isn't a way to do it with one query in mysql. By far the cleanest code solution is to pass in the table name from a variable. Even better would be to correct the poor database schema design and make all of those tables a single table, so that a single simple update will do the job. But since you said this is old code, it's likely that would be impractical in this case.

Comment: it could exist a " Select Update "? something more with more subqueries? Don't need to be in one query. The other tables "table1, table2" etc, are really diferent, cannot be merged. Is like one is for receipt, other for payments, other for invoices, etc, only share one column name between them.

Comment: Then that means the column shared between those tables should be in it's own table. All the differences can be in separate tables.